# Unsigned char out of range

Tags: for-loop, pic, unsigned-char

I am trying to figure out, how to use an `unsigned char` type of a variable inside a `for` loop, while not "breaking" out of range for `unsigned char`, which can vary form 0 to 255.

```c
    main(void) {
        TRISC = 0;
        LATC = 0;
        unsigned char j;
    
        for (j = 0; j <= 255 ; j++){
            LATC = j;
            __delay_ms(1000);
        }
        return;
    }
```

This is code in C, where PIC is programmed. "TRISC = 0" means setting port C as an output and "LATC" is referring to port C itself. Basically I want to assign values from including 0 to 255 to this port. But if I try to compile this, the compiler (xc8) returns following two warnings:

[image]

[image]

I cannot quite understand what these two are saying, but I assume it has to do something with variable `j` exceeding the limit value of `unsigned char`, that is 255 (in last iteration `j = 256`, which is not allowed/defined).
However, this code gets compiled and works as meant. But I still want to write and understand a code that assigns port C the value of 255 without entering "prohibited" range of values.

*P.S. I would use any other variable type than `unsigned char` or `char`, however to ports in PICs only these two types can be applied directly (without conversion).

Comment: Memory is cheap - change j to unsigned int.

Comment: @cup Same warning. Must be due to the fact that you can assign only ```char``` to any port of a PIC. That is the only reason I'm using ```char``` here.

Comment: Try casting before assigning

Comment: Sidenote: j will never reach 256, it will overflow to 0, so your for loop condition is basically an endless loop

Comment: This: `j <= 255`is always true if `j`is 8 Bit. So if you want your loop count from 0...255 you had to change it.

Comment: @cup Memory is not cheap in a 8-bit PIC microcontroller. One must also consider the execution speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j <= 255` is always true if `j` is only 8 Bit wide.

This version should work:

```
main(void) {
    TRISC = 0;
    LATC = 0;
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j <= 255 ; j++){
        LATC = (unsigned char)j;
        __delay_ms(1000);
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, in microcontroller firmware, you should not return from `main()`. Your `main()` should include some kind of endless loop.

`j <= 255` is always true for a `uint8_t` variable. Because j can't be 256. Adding 1 to j when it's 255, makes it 0, not 256.

As others have suggested, using an 16-bit integer, signed or unsigned, is the easiest and the cleanest way. However, in performance sensitive loops you may prefer to stick with 8 bit loop counters as these are the fastest ones for a 8-bit PIC microcontroller.

This particular one-time loop can be written as:

```c
uint8_t j = 0;
do {
    LATC = j++;
    __delay_ms(1000);
} while (j != 0);
```